# Angular - How to use the result of an observable, inside another observable?

Tags: angular, observable

I have an observable, to which I subscribe and I do some operations on the result value (a `reduce()` and a `map()`).

But inside that observable I would like to call another observable that just returns a number, and I need that number in my `map()`.

Here an example:

```
this.getYearlyDataByIdAndYear(292, 2019).subscribe(result = > {
        let ferienSaldo: FerienSaldo;
        this.getVacationsYearlyDataByIdAndYear(292, 2019).subscribe(result = > {
            // this is my inner observable and I need to save this result, and use it below!
            ferienSaldo = result;
        });
        this.yearlyOverview = result.reduce < Array < YearlyOverview >> ((prev, current, i, all) = > {
                // some code that is not important
                let overviewVar: YearlyOverview = {
                    saldo: ferienSaldo.value
                };
                prev.push(newTLOverview);
            }
            return prev;
        }, new Array < YearlyOverview > ())
});
```

basically as you can see, inside my initial Observable, I will need the value from the inner one, and I will copy that value inside my `reduce()` to assign it to a new object I'm creating!

The issue with my code is, the "let ferienSaldo" variable cannot be accessed inside the second observable, and besides that I'm sure there is a better way to combine this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the two calls don't depend on each other, so you can run them in parallel in a `forkJoin`

```
forkJoin([
  this.getYearlyDataByIdAndYear(292, 2019).pipe(
    tap(result => this.result1 = result)
  ),
  this.getVacationsYearlyDataByIdAndYear(292, 2019).pipe(
    tap(result => this.result2 = result)
  )
]).subscribe(() => {
  // process this.result1 and this.result2
  // TODO: more meaningful property names
});
```

Edit:

I used tap because I like to keep my subscribe body clean. You can also return the results in an array to subscribe:

```
forkJoin([
  this.getYearlyDataByIdAndYear(292, 2019),
  this.getVacationsYearlyDataByIdAndYear(292, 2019)
]).subscribe(result => {
  // process result[0] and result[1]
});
```

The second option looks cleaner in a trivial example like this, but I find it's annoying to couple your subscribe body to the array indices - especially when you make changes.

Comment: exactly, the 2 calls don't depend on each other, they just use the same parameters, and the inner one is a small call, it just returns me some value from another DB, I will try your forkJoin then

Comment: great it works, the only thing, I had an error until I changed "(result: [])" in just "(result)"! now I can call result[0] and result[1], thank you